# How can I do my index/match to work in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro that uses Index/match functions to match and pull data from one sheet into another. I did it in Excel and it works perfect. However the reports are "dynamic" (the size changes) so I need the last row of my code to be dynamic as well. 
The following is what I have done. I'm NOW getting a "type mismatch" error (I emphasize "now" since every time I find a solution for one error another pop's up).

```
   Dim prosheet As Worksheet

   Dim prosheet2 As Worksheet

   Set prosheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("shipstation")

   Set prosheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("macrotestfb")

   lr1 = prosheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   lr2 = prosheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   lrship = prosheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

   lrindex = prosheet2.Cells(Rows.Column, 14).End(xlUp).Row

   'CALCULATE SHIPPING COST

   For x = prosheet.range("j6") To lrship

       x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(prosheet2.range("a1:n" &  lrindex), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(prosheet.range("a6:a" & lr1), prosheet2.range("a1:a" & lr2), 0), prosheet2.range("f2"))

   Next x
```

Answer (score 2):

Match, in its non array form, only likes one value in the first criterion and not a range.

Also WorksheetFunction.Match will throw an error that will stop the code if a match is not found.

I like to pull the match into its own line and test for the error.

I also adjusted your For statement.

There is no detriment to searching an entire column so I got rid of a few of you last row searches as they are not needed.

```
Dim prosheet As Worksheet
Dim prosheet2 As Worksheet
Dim x As Long
Dim t As Long
Set prosheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("shipstation")
Set prosheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("macrotestfb")

lrship = prosheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'CALCULATE SHIPPING COST

For x = 6 To lrship
    t = 0
    On Error Resume Next
        t = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(prosheet.Range("A" & x), prosheet2.Range("A:A"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If t > 0 Then
        prosheet.Cells(x, "J").Value = prosheet2.Range("F"&t)
    Else
        prosheet.Cells(x, "J").Value = "Item does not Exist"
    End If
Next x
```

Comment: Hi, first thanks for your time...the code works almost perfectly. I did some minor adaptations and it runs great...now i found another issue...the index function will not work in some records, I'm getting this error message..."Unable to get the index property of the worksheet function class"...looking at if I found that in every instance the code does not work the lookup value contains numbers and letters ex. 12365E...should I change the data type of the variables x and y?

Comment: What is the value of F2 on the "shipstation" sheet and what is the value of t when the code stops.  And what are the changes you made? as this could be affecting the outcome.

Comment: ...that is one of the "minor adaptations" I made..I change the value of ("f2") in the index function to ("f" & t), otherwise it will always give me f2 only..after the change the value of ("f" & t) is 77 and t is 77 as well..

Comment: Where you had the `prosheet2.range("f2")` in your code is the column number from which the value will be returned.  so if it was 2 it would return the value from column B, 3 would b column c and so on.  I think you do not have the correct form for your formula, which column on "shipstation"  do you want to return?  Is it always the same column?

Comment: ...I want to return from column "F", and yes its always the same column..

Answer (score 0):

Note:

Instead of an `Index`/`Match` combo which you might use on the worksheet, you can use `Application.Match` in VBA. Something like this:

```
Sub GetMatch
    Dim indexRng As Range, matchRng as Range

    Set indexRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
    Set matchRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B10")

    debug.print indexRng.Cells(Application.Match("something",matchRng,0)).Value
End Sub
```